# Cannot reach UEFI setting because Windows 10 wil not reboot properly

Tags: windows-10, uefi

### Short version

What options are there to enter the UEFI firmware settings when rebooting into them is not possible?

### Long version

The situation is as follows: My computer runs fine, but when I reboot the computer, the computer will freeze up. My backlighted keyboard will flash, one of my coolers (I suspect the GPU cooler) will shortly run on max and stop doing that and after that nothing. I can get out of this by pressing the reboot button on my PC. I have not given this matter much attention, because turning the computer on and off works fine, as does sleeping, so it is seldom an issue.

Now I want to change something in the UEFI settings (because I suspect my virtualization options are [not as they should be](https://superuser.com/questions/866962/why-does-virtualbox-only-have-32-bit-option-no-64-bit-option-on-windows-7) ). My first hunch was to press some key when the computer is starting up, but this does not work: the first things that I see after the monitor turns on is the Windows log in screen. I found the regular procedure (in short, press shift when pressing restart in the Windows menu and pick troubleshoot/advanced/uefi settings). The computer starts to reboot, but the problem in the previous paragraph kicks in. After I get the computer to reboot properly again, the option to go to the UEFI settings is forgotten and I am presented with the regular Windows login screen.

The next steps I need to take are more time intensive and I wondered what my best course of action would be. Is there an alternative way to enter the UEFI settings? I probably should fix my restarting problem, but the (preliminary) research I have done so far suggest I might need to update the firmware of the motherboard or reinstall Windows, both which I would like to avoid for now.

Comment: 1) The GPU cooler is probably doing its own thing: it starts on maximum, for safety, before the GPU BIOS sets the speed of the fan. 2) If the disk drive with Windows 10 didn't have its data cable connected, there would be no Windows 10 to get in the way. 3) Which UEFI settings are you proposing to change? If you edit your question to tell us then we might be able to make useful suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I want to change some settings concerning virtualization, or at least check their current status.

Comment: You didn't say if the PC is a laptop or "tower". If the latter, then disconnecting the disk drive data cable is simple, but if you are uncomfortable doing that then let us know. Related info: [After Windows 10 upgrade I can no longer access BIOS](http://superuser.com/a/948617/272824)

Comment: "What options are there to enter the UEFI firmware settings when rebooting into them is not possible?" - Boot to the `Advanced Startup`, the option to do this, requires a working Windows installation.  You can also acomplish the task by forcing Windows to fail at its boot attempts three times.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It is a tower. I am not uncomfortable disconnecting the SATA cable, though I would prefer not doing so.

Comment: @Ramhound I am aware of this option, but my particular problem is that I cannot boot to something special, like the Advanced Startup or the UEFI settings. The computer will not reboot after I give the command to do so and "forgets" that it was a special boot after I have remedied this.

Comment: @Niels You could try the [Intel® Processor Identification Utility](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/7838) to see if "Intel (R) Virtualization Technology" is enabled and whichever other options you require, like "Intel Vt-x with Extended Page Tables". Assuming it's an Intel processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. The solution, in case someone else thinks he or she has this problem:

My computer was rebooting just fine and entered the UEFI settings just like it should. I do not know if it worked if I would used the F2 or DEL keys (it probably would, I just did not try it anymore), but just using the normal Windows 10 facilities to reach it worked.

The problem turned out to be my graphics card (or me, that depends how you look at it). I have four output ports on my card, 2 HDMI and 2 display port. I have an old monitor with only a VGA port for the input. Only when Windows loaded the video output would switch to the display port I was using with an adapter.

Off topic:
The previous time I was in the UEFI settings, was when I installed Windows after building it and was eager to see what it could do. At that time I used a television (HDMI connection obviously) for screen temporarily, while I waited for the VGA/Display port adapter tocome with the mail. Had I thought of this earlier...

Answer (score 1):

My problem turned out to be the following: monitor connected with DisplayPort never showed the "Press 'del' or 'F2' to enter BIOS screen" because the monitor restart was slower than the reboot of my pc.

Connecting to a monitor with hdmi solved it for me (and clicking the boot to uefi setting).

Answer (score 0):

See the Boot options menu in  [Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference). You can access the Firmware menu from there. The *Entry points into WinRE* section of that page describes how to restart to recovery mode. The following are the two that are likely to be relevant; choose one of the following two:

- From the login screen, click Shutdown, then hold down the Shift key while selecting Restart.
- In Windows 10, select Start > Settings > Update & security > Recovery > under Advanced Startup, click Restart now.

Note that the article does not make it clear how to get to the UEFI Firmware menu after the restart. Click Troubleshoot, then click Advanced Options.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @user34660, but I am very familiar with this procedure. The problem is my Windows will not reboot correctly afterwards (well never, but also after these steps.)

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked and even more recently was the removal of the CMOS battery.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I know of to get to the UEFI settings is using the BIOS. There has to be a key even though it's not displayed.

The most common keys are:

- <kbd>F2</kbd>
- <kbd>F12</kbd>
- <kbd>DEL</kbd>

Try them immediately after applying power. It is usually boot option but BIOS Setup might be there too.

If you can supply the manufacturer and model of the computer the manual should tell you what the key is.

Comment: These shortcuts don't normally work on modern Windows 8 and Windows 10 devices due to faster boot times.

Comment: I have looked up the commands for this in the manual myself, but to no avail.

Comment: Totally incorrect Ramhound. The OS has nothing to do with it. You are thinking of F8 for safe mode which no longer works in Windows 10 because of the fast boot. The function keys to get in to the BIOS are part of the BIOS and have nothing to do with the OS.

Comment: I am still going with a key sequence. Why do you have a problem telling us the make and manufacturer of the computer?

Comment: @ZiggyStardust, I have assembled the computer myself. If you are mainly interested in the manufacturer of the motherboard: it is an Asus Z170M-Plus. I have looked through the manual myself and identified the two buttons (DEL or F2) that would get me into the Bios setup, but me pressing these buttons during startup has no effect. I have no visual feedback or instructions, my video card will start outputting a signal when the Windows logon screen is visible.

Comment: OK. From a cold boot (power off) immediately start tapping the DEL key (or F2) as soon as you turn the power on. Don't wait for something to show up on the screen. Start tapping the DEL key right away.Also make sure you try it from a cold boot. It won't always work from a warm boot.

Comment: @ZiggyStardust I have tried your suggestion, it gives the same pattern as if I would try to reboot into the UEFI settings (so the system fails to start, or at least display anything), which might be important information. Perhaps the settings are loaded, but I can't see them because my screen does not awaken until the Windows screen loads. Just brainstorming here.

Comment: I am going to ask first.... the DEL OR F2? I have seen one or the other but have never seen both. Anyway.... If the DEL or F2 work it should be sitting at the BIOS screen when the video card finally gets going. The fact that is isn't might be because the keyboard is bad. Do you have another keyboard you can try. The fact that it is a key sequence but that sequence doesn't work might point to bigger problems.

Comment: From the manual you are correct: F2 or DEL immediately when power is applied. If you miss it right when power is supplied then try <ctrl-alt-del> The fact that is doesn't work as advertised would imply that either the keyboard is shot or.... the motherboard.

Comment: I know this is like 4 years after the fact. But again, I had a problem with another ASUS MB more recently. And I finally figured out the only way to fix it. Remove the CMOS battery. 

Anyway, thank for all the help and suggestions.